# how to implement autonomous navigation using lidar and hector?

Tags: ros, slam, lidar, differential-drive

I want to make an autonomous mobile robot, which can localise itself and navigate to the goal in an unknown environment. 
As sensor, i just have a RPLidar to get laser scan, that's it. I used Hector SLAM to make a map of the room. But how do I implement navigation for the robot?
Move_Base, (specifically base_local_planner) requires odometry data. while hector gives pose update and slam out pose, they have a different message type compared to odom.

Please help.

Comment: Even I have the same issue
can u help me if you got the result? Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.ros.org/amcl
You should try this and take a look at http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map
It provides the code to use amcl and RVIZ to navigate. Now you just substitute the fastslam here with hector slam, and write your own controller to replace the one in the package.